# Freenx stopped working after upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, freenx

I installed Ubuntu 11.04, installed FreeNX server and FreeNX client for Windows from http://www.nomachine.com/download-client-windows.php. I was able to connect to my ubuntu from my windows laptop.

With the recent upgrade of Ubuntu 11.10 whenever I try to launch my FreeNX from my laptop, it accepts the password, initialises the session and just when it is about to display the window the window suddenly closes and says "the connection with remote server was shut down"

This is driving me mad. Can someone please tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your nxclient is not configured to run unity. In connection settings, (click Configure at the login screen of nxclient), set desktop to UNIX and Custom. In settings tab on the right, select "Run the default X client script on server" and it will work.

If you want a better thing (as unity 3d is not very good in NX for me), you can use the "Run the following command" option and insert one of the sessions you have available on your server machine (maybe you'll need to install them):

`gnome-session --session=classic-gnome` for classic gnome 2 (if you installed the fallback session)

or
`ubuntu-2d` (or 2d-unity, I'm not sure) will give unity 2d for example.

I never tried but I think if you install fxce (apt-get install xubuntu-desktop) and use the command `startfxce4` instead of the `gnome-session` command, it will run with fxce as I use this command to start fxce session on a XRDP server without problems (and I connect using windows RDP client or Remmina).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a installer script to compile and install freenx server on Ubuntu 11.10, which works with unity. see my blog post: http://notepad2.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/install-freenx-server-on-ubuntu-1110.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.